# create a variable from a condition sas

Tags: if-statement, boolean, sas, conditional-statements

I would want create a new variable with a condition if  x1 is positive the new variable takes 1 else 0. My directory is 'dir' and my sas dataset is 'exemple'. SAS not creates me the x2 variable.

```
data dir.exemple;
set exemple;
if x1<0 then x2=1;
else x2=0;
end;
run;
```

The log is

```
NOTE: Variable x1 is uninitialized.
NOTE: The data set DIR.EXEMPLE has 1 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.16 seconds
      cpu time            0.04 seconds
```

Comment: Check the log, it will point you straight to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jess has said, you should look at your whole log first to check for error messages. Right now even if your `libname` statement path is correct, you'll still get errors.

If you want the condition if `x1` is positive then it should be "x1`>`0", not x1`<`0. It's only positive if it's greater than zero. And you don't need the `end;` since you're not using a `do` or `select` statement.

```
libname dir 'C:\sasdata';

data dir.exemple;
set exemple;
if x1>0 then x2=1;
else x2=0;

run;
```